# contact form submits on both true and false captcha answers

Tags: php

As am nearing 80, I am probably too old to be doing this anymore. In spite of retiring from a lifetime of main-frame programming over 20 years ago, I know next to nothing about multitude of modern programming languages. My form works but cannot seem to add a simple captcha to block submitting on wrong answers or recent attack of spambots. (Cannot use image captchas as elderly brethren will never negotiate them :)  Also wish to avoid javascript for security reasons.

PROBLEM: FORM ECHOS FALSE ANSWER OK, BUT SENDS FOR ALL ANSWERS 12 OR NOT
(CAPTCHA PORTION SHOWN)

```
<BR>Prevent Robot Spam: What is 6 + 6? (Number)

<input type='text' name='quiz' id='quiz' size='8' /> &nbsp;
<?php

$quiz = $_POST['quiz'];

if ($quiz == '' || $quiz == 12) {

// true answer, form sent

} else {
echo 'false answer, please back < browser and try again';

exit; 

} 

?>
<input type='submit' name='Sent From Universe Lodge Web-Site' id='submit' value='SEND YOUR MESSAGE' /></BR>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why are you accepting non-answers - `if ($quiz == '' ...)`? Shouldn't it only be for correct answers - `if ($quiz == 12) { ...}`. Also, you should check if `$_POST['quiz']` is set first, and if not you could set it as a false answer - `$quiz = (isset($_POST['quiz'])) ? $_POST['quiz'] : 'wrong answer';`

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't randomly generating your math question it would still be pretty easy to spam your form. [This page has step-by-step instructions on preventing CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_CSRF_Guard) (including code that will automatically alter your forms to contain a nonce token). Essentially you need to:

1. generate a session-based token when your page is loaded
2. include that token in a hidden form field
3. check that the token is present and matches session token on form submission

Awesome that you're programming at 80! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it
    
Prevent Robot Spam: What is 6 + 6? (Number)

```
<input type='text' name='quiz' id='quiz' size='8' /> &nbsp;
<?php
if(isset($_POST['quiz'])){
     $quiz = $_POST['quiz'];

     if ($quiz == 12) {

         // true answer, form sent

     } else {
            echo 'false answer, please back < browser and try again';

           exit; 

     } 
}


?>
<input type='submit' name='Sent From Universe Lodge Web-Site' id='submit' value='SEND YOUR MESSAGE' /></BR>
```